# Accessing HDFS jceks in python script

Tags: python, hdfs, jceks

I want to access HDFS jceks (password alias is created) in python script for secure login. Can anyone help with with python code /steps to do so.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You may use the hadoop configuration to access the password from python code.

Only thing you would need is to instanciate a hadoop configuration and use the property  `hadoop.security.credential.provider.path` to set and retrieve the password using `getPassword`

You could use Spark also to read the jecks password from inside your code:

Python:

```
spark1 = SparkSession.builder.appName("xyz").master("yarn").enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").getOrCreate()
x = spark1.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
x.set("hadoop.security.credential.provider.path", "jceks://file///localpathtopassword")
a = x.getPassword("<password alias>")
passw = ""
for i in range(a.__len__()):
   passw = passw + str(a.__getitem__(i))
```

In the above code you shall get the password string in `passw`

Comment: For just connecting to Jceks I wouldn't prefer using Spark. Is there any other approach to connect to hdfs jceks pls

Comment: Did you find a way to get the password without using Spark?